# Display an image that's uploaded into app resources

Tags: google-app-maker

The App settings page has a resources tab that I can upload images to. Great, so I uploaded an image. Now I can get the link (e.g.

```
resources/google-apps-script-xxx-yyy-zzz-aaa-1234565789.png
```

and create image widgets on pages with that link.

That looks great in the editor, but the moment I publish a deployment, I only see a broken imagelink.

Interestingly, I can right click on the broken image placeholder and "open image in new tab", which then opens the image without any problems.

Now, I can totally work around this by uploading the image to drive and paste a link from there, but it's nicer to put all the resources into the app itself.

Any suggestion on how to properly paste the link into the image url field ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding an Image widget, you will actually want to open your 'Widgets' panel in the editor and scroll all the way down until you reach the section called 'Your Images', drag your static image onto your page and then you should be able to resize it from there to fit in with the flow of your page. See the image:

[image: Import Static Resources]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work out ;(

At first, I thought it would work, for about a day. Then the UI stopped showing the image again. When I looked, I realized that pulling the image from the "Your images" portion of the widgets does the same than choosing a regular image and using the resource link manually. So I still don't know what's going on. Very strange.

Comment: Update: The issue has something to do with third party cookies (which are turned off).